# Aligning CSS background-image with offsetted image center axis

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'd like to align image files (as `.png`) with an offsetted image center axis using CSS's `background-`*-properties.

Imagine having the following document:

```html
<div class="my-icon" data-category="1">abc</div>
<div class="my-icon" data-category="2">def</div>
<div class="my-icon" data-category="1">ghi</div>
```

with the following style sheet:

```css
.my-icon {
    background-position: center left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-left: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
}

.my-icon[data-category="1"] {
    background-image: url('...../icon-1.png');
}

.my-icon[data-category="2"] {
    background-image: url('...../icon-2.png');
}
```

I can align the icon as follows:

| `background-position: center center;` | `background-position: center left;` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

##### However, what I want is the following:

[image]

I'd like the image's center axis to be aligned with an axis offsetted by `x` pixels from the left-hand side of the `div`.

How is this feat achievable using pure CSS? (Without JS/JQuery?)

Comment: you need to know both images dimension to achieve this

Comment: The dimensions are not known until page load and might change at any time during the deployment phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML and CSS seems incomplete. I assume your icons are wrapped in a parent element, so I wrapped your icons in a `.my-element` div.

Using background-image to position elements and their backgrounds relative to a parent is very tricky. I would suggest using CSS Grid to position icons. Here's an example using `display: grid`

```css
.my-element {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 38px;
}
.my-icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.my-icon[data-category="1"] {
    grid-area: 1/1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/450/332);
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin: 10px;
}
.my-icon[data-category="2"] {
    grid-area: 1/1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/40/40);
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element">
  abc
  <div class="my-icon" data-category="1">def</div>
  <div class="my-icon" data-category="2">ghi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would post a reply, as this is not actually an answer, but I don't have enough rep...

If you have the possibility of editing the HTML, I would suggest doing something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="my-icon" data-category="1" style="width: 50%;"></div> <!--image-->
    <div style="width: 50%:">abc</div>
</div>
```

use classes instead of inline css ofcourse.

Otherwise [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) is an example of setting offset with percentages and statements (left, right). So something along the lines of `background-position: 50% center;`